# Form is not posting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send data from a textfield to my database. When I run the code I get no errors. But the code isnt posting the data to the database. I cant see whats wrong, can someone look what is wrong?

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./send/send1.php">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_1" name="data_1" placeholder="Data 1" />

<button name="send">Send</button>
</form>
</html>
```

send1.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

?>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<?php
$correct = true;

$data_1 = $_POST['data_1'] ;

?>
</table>
<?php
if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');
    $query = "UPDATE table SET data_1=" . $data_1 . " WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['ID'] ."'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($adres_1));

    echo "<br /><br />Success.<br />\n";
} else {

    echo "<br /><br />Error.<br />\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<button name="send">Send</button>` -> No `type='submit'`. How you able to submit ?

Comment: And the very first thing, you have not given your full code.

Comment: @Nana "submit" is the default type of a `<button>`, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: I was not aware of this @VolkerK. Learnt newly. *Thanks !*

Comment: @Nana, this is my full code. When I run the script I get the message "Success". But nothing is written to my database

Comment: If this is your full code. Then, from where `array($adres_1)` comes into `$stmt->execute(array($adres_1));` ? I am not able to see any where you used `array($adres_1)`.

Answer (score 1):

a) your script needs more error handling.
Before accessing `$_POST['data_1']`, you should test its existence, e.g. via `isset()`.
Your database code doesn't have any error handling, too. Either [set the error mode to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)  or (/and) make sure you test each and every return value of the PDO::* methods.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');
$query = "UPDATE table SET data_1=" . $data_1 . " WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['ID'] ."'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
if ( !$stmt ) {
    yourErrorHandler('could not prepare statement', $db->error);
}
else if ( !$stmt->execute(array($adres_1)) ) {
    yourErrorHandler('could execute statement', $stmt->error);
}
else if ( 1>$stmt->rowCount() ) {
    // no record has been updates
}
else {
    // at least one record has been updated
}
```

b) `$stmt->execute(array($adres_1));` What is `$adres_1`?  It's not anywhere else in *that* code.
c) Your code is prone to [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You can fix that e.g. by using [prepared statements + parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

The whole code looks like small parts of other scripts have been copy&pasted without understanding what those snippets do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autocommit? maybe your db changes are being rolled back. Try adding an extra COMMIT SQL statement.

Comment: No, I am not using a commit statement. But the SQL statement is working in phpmyadmin

Comment: Perhaps PHPMYADMIN has autocommit set to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit your code. Then only the values are send to the php file by the POST method.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<form name="reaction" method="post" action="./send/send1.php">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="data_1" name="data_1" placeholder="Data 1" />

<input type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
</form>
</html>
```

**send1.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

?>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<?php
$correct = true;

if ($_POST['send']) {
    $data_1 = $_POST['data_1'] ;
}

?>
</table>
<?php
if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'root', '');
    $query = "UPDATE table SET data_1=" . $data_1 . " WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['ID'] ."'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($adres_1));

    echo "<br /><br />Success.<br />\n";
} else {

    echo "<br /><br />Error.<br />\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still get the message "Success." but nothing is posted to the database

Comment: do echo of your query and run it manually in your database. `echo $query` and debug it.